# build sum of multiple subquery results

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum, subquery

I am trying to build a sum of the results from multiple subqueries. 
I have numerous periods defined with two variables:

```
declare 
@left1 date = '2014-06-25',
@return1 date ='2014-08-21',

 @left2 date = '2014-10-29',
 @return2 date = '2015-03-15',

@left3 date = '2015-04-21',
@return3 date = '2015-09-19'
```

Then I am calculating the days between these two dates but ultimately I would like to add them up and get a total:

```
select  datediff(day, @left1, @return1 )

select  datediff(day, @left2, @return2 )

select  datediff(day, @left3, @return3 )
```

I thought of CTE's but it didn't work out. What is a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure you just need some basic addition.

```
select datediff(day, @left1, @return1 )
     + datediff(day, @left2, @return2 )
     + datediff(day, @left3, @return3 )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select  
   datediff(day, @left1, @return1 ) + 
   datediff(day, @left2, @return2 ) + 
   datediff(day, @left3, @return3 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,[LEFT],[Return])) AS TOTALDAYS
FROM
(
  select @left1 AS [Left],@return1 AS [Return]
  UNION ALL
  select @left2 AS [Left],@return2 AS [Return]
  UNION ALL
  select @left3 AS [Left],@return3 AS [Return]
) X
```

Comment: Your shorthand wasn't wrong, [but you may like this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). '

Answer (score 2):

This query can help you:

```
Select 
    sum(NbDay) as totaldiffday
From (
        select  datediff(day, @left1, @return1 ) As NbDay
        Union
        select  datediff(day, @left2, @return2 ) As NbDay 
        Union 
        select  datediff(day, @left3, @return3 ) As NbDay
) as SubQuery
```